# inserting dashed border within a ul to print css

Tags: html, css

I'm inconvenience when printing a line dashed inside a ul, the line is not appearing in Print file, but if you add the div.linha outside ul, works correctly.

link http://jsfiddle.net/joseferreira/nf6emxb8/

```
<ul>
```

**Clientes Vendidos (1)**

- **Nome do cliente:**Google

```
        <li><b>Data Cadastro:26/02/1991</b></li>
        <li>Observações:
            <ul>

                <li>dtets</li>
            </ul>
        <!-- -->
        </li>
    </ul>
<!-- -->
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a dashed outline border on all ul elements just add

```
ul {
    border:1px dashed #eceeca;
}
```

inside the media query css.

like this,

```css
@media print {
  .linha {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    display: block;
    background: #f00;
    border: 10px solid #c9cacb;
  }
  ul {
    border: 1px dashed #eceeca;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class='linha'></div>
  <li><b>Clientes Vendidos (1)</b>

    <ul>
      <li><b>Nome do cliente:</b>Google</li>
      <li><b>Data Cadastro:26/02/1991</b>
      </li>
      <li>Observações:
        <ul>
          <li>dtets</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- -->
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now to see for yourself the output in print media, copy the entire code in your editor save it as html file and run it in your local webserver and try to print the page. Even in print preview you will notice the dashed outline .

hope this helps

Update::: [new fiddle as well](http://jsfiddle.net/nf6emxb8/2/)